# Equivalent to DateTime.Parse in NodaTime?

Tags: c#, .net, nodatime, datetime-parsing

If I have a string like "2020-12-15T12:10:00.202" how can I parse this into `NodaTime.LocalDateTime` directly, rather than doing something like:

`LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(DateTime.Parse("2020-12-15T12:10:00.202"))`

And similarly for the other NodaTime types like `LocalDate`, `Instant` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use a [`LocalDateTimePattern`](https://nodatime.org/3.0.x/api/NodaTime.Text.LocalDateTimePattern.html). For example:

```cs
// Note: patterns are thread-safe and immutable. Various patterns are provided as
// static properties on the relevant pattern class. If you can't use one of those
// patterns, it's often useful to store the pattern in a static readonly field.
var pattern = LocalDateTimePattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fff");

// There's no Parse/TryParse separation - there's just Parse, which returns a
// ParseResult<T> that indicates success/failure.
ParseResult<LocalDateTime> parsed = pattern.Parse("2020-12-15T12:10:00.202");

// Note: if you're okay with invalid input causing an exception, just use
// parsed.Value directly - it will throw a descriptive exception if parsing failed.
if (parsed.Success)
{
    LocalDateTime result = parsed.Value;
    // Use the result here
}
else
{
    // Handle the failure
}
```

For more details about text handling, see the [section in the user guide](https://nodatime.org/3.0.x/userguide/text).

Note that there's no *direct* equivalent of `DateTime.Parse` itself, that tries multiple different date/time formats automatically - but you can use a `CompositePatternBuilder<T>` to try multiple patterns when parsing if you want.